# Positioning BootStrap daterangepicker calendar

Tags: bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using [BootStrap Datepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/). I want to load/position the calendar at top of the field. How can i do this ?

Currently it is loading like this -
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make the calendar appear above the input instead of below, change the "drops" setting to "up".

```
$(element).daterangepicker({
    drops: 'up'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone uses it with angular:

```
  [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"
```